# Erro ao gerar Controller MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Bom dia colegas, estou tentando gerar um controller no MVC 5 com VS 2019 e estou tomando a seguinte mensagem de erro.

Alguem poderia me ajudar com este problema?

[image: Tela para gerar o controlador]

> Erro ao executar gerador de código selecionado: 'O valor -1 está fora
>   do intervalo aceitável de [0,2147483647]. Nome do parâmetro: value'

[image: Mensagem de erro]

Comment: Tenta colocar com o checkbox de Layout desmarcado.

Comment: Seu projeto tem algum erro de compilação?

Comment: George, não aparece nenhum erro...

Comment: Se você tenta gerar para outras models da certo?

Comment: Paulo, desmarquei todos os checkbox e mesmo assim ainda continua o problema.

Comment: George, acontece para todos os modelos..

Comment: O erro que vc está tendo também foi relatado aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401867/erro-ao-gerar-controle-no-asp-net-mvc?noredirect=1#comment788631_401867
Parece ser um problema na versão 16.2 do VS 2019: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/626755/error-running-the-selected-code-generator-value-1.html
Mas parece que isso foi corrigido na versão 16.2.1: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#--visual-studio-2019-vers%C3%A3o-1621-visual-studio-2019-version-1621-
O VS que vc tá usando já está na versão 16.2.1?

Comment: a minha versão é a 16.2.0
vou tentar atualizar aqui...

Comment: Raquel, era isso mesmo...atualizei e resolveu...
Obrigado

Comment: Estou utilizando o Visual Studio 2022. No meu caso foi resolvido dessa forma: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn3Aghypzcs

Answer (score -1):

Esse erro ja deu na empresa onde eu trabalho, e chegamos a conclusão de que o problema é no visual studio.

Mas como esse meio de gerar o controller é algo muito simples, nós criamos classes normais e só modificamos pra ser um controller.

Se você trabalha com View, e da o mesmo erro, tambem da pra fazer a mesma coisa, mas na hora que esta criando a classe, cria a view com .cshtml, porque por padrao ele cria com .cs, e na hora que o arquivo estiver aberto, ele não tera as devidas formatações(aquela perte que diferencias as cores do @Html ...)